# I would like to override a method in C#, but I have a different signature

Tags: c#

The base class user should access the original method

```
class A
 public init()
```

The derived class user should aceess ONLY the derived method.

```
class B
 public init(int info)
```

I cannot use "override" bc there's a different signature.
What options do I have so that the derived class user does not see two methods.

Notes.
All in all I just need two classes that share some code. Inheritance is not a must.
But simplicity for the user of B is a priority.

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong structurally, give us the details of what you would like to do.

Comment: Virtual/Override implies calling the methods the same way. what do you imagine the call would look like?

Answer (score 10):

This is a big code smell (and violates some basic OOP tenets) and, to the best of my knowledge, can not be done in any language. In OOP, an instance of `B` is an instance of `A`; this is [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming). So if `A` has a public method named `init` accepting no parameters, then so does `B`.

What are you trying to do this for?

Edit: Now that you've added the edit that states that inheritance is not a must, just use [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) to share code. Give `B` a private instance of `A`, for example.

Comment: but base class user should access to it.

Comment: @yapiskan: Thanks, I overlooked his implicit statement that `A.init` be public.

Comment: Nope, it can be done in C++, and it doesn't violate anything.

Comment: @Earwicker: how? in c++ you can only overload function, not override.

Comment: @Yossarian - private inheritance.

Comment: I think the main conflict with OP's situation is that inheritance can be used in a way that you're not relying on polymorphism, but are simply trying to reduce duplicate code (e.g. a generic base `Repository<T>`, in order to avoid writing a similar `Update` method for every entity type, and `FooRepository : Repository<Foo>` for methods that are unique to the `Foo` entity). The OP may not be relying on polymorphism here, but the compiler expects him to be able to rely on it nonetheless.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Liskov principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) you simply cannot do that, because it would violate this principle. The best thing you can to is override `init()` in the derived class and make it throw an exception every time it's invoked, stating that the user should use `init(int info)` and rely on the test to catch the errors.

Why you can't simple replace the init() method or even make it protected?

The Liskov principle states (rephrased) that where an instance of `class A` is required, an isntance of `class B extends A` can be passed.
If a method expects `A` and wants to call `init()` on it and you pass `B` (which `extends A`) to it with a `protected init()` the method will fail. This is the reason why the code will not even compile.

Comment: It isn't necessarily covered by the Liskov principle. Where a language supports private inheritance, it has several options. If D privately inherits B, then it could be that D is not a B (in other words, they are not related types - D just inherits implementation), and so Liskov is irrelevant. Or it could be that D is assignable to a B reference/pointer and then it fully is a B, and so Liskov is observed just fine. On the other hand, your suggestion to throw an exception in the derived class would very much violate Liskov.

Comment: Earwicker: agree - throwing an exception violates the principle.

In OO languages inheritance usually is 'is a' relation, but technically, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is impossible, due to the nature of the type system. Any instance of B can be thought of as an A, so you can call any of A's methods (including `Init()`). The best you can do is overload `Init()` in B and throw an exception to catch this at runtime.

```
public class B
{
     void Init()
     {
         throw new NotSupportedException();
     }
}
```

Comment: I'd say that's just about the worst thing you could do! :) Why not pick a solution that catches problems during compilation?

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to some answers/comments here, what you are asking for *would* have a real use if it existed:

```
class Derived : Base
{
```

This can be seen by considering the workaround:

```
class Derived
{
    private Base _base = new Base();
```

In other words, it's not really a base class at all, but a hidden part of the implementation.

The downside with this workaround is: what Base has an abstract method that you have to supply? You have to write this:

```
class Derived
{
    class ActualDerived : Base
    {
        // override abstract method(s)
    }

    private Base _base = new ActualDerived();
```

This is the whole point of private inheritance (as found in C++) - it's for situations when you want to inherit the implementation but not the "interface" (in the informal sense).

But in C#, it's not available.

Comment: This doesn't give you polymorphism though. That is, sure, what he's looking for can be accomplished but in a way that violates his requirement that B derives from A.

Comment: @Jason - Wrong - the OP says "Inheritance is not a must."

Comment: And you've updated your answer to say the same as this one now! Strange.

Comment: @Earwicker: His statement that "[i]nheritance is not a must" is an edit that came after I made my initial post.

Answer (score 1):

Presumabely A and B have something in common. Can you factor that out into a different base class?

```
public class Base
{
    ... common stuff ...
}
public class A : Base
{
    public void Init()
    {
    }
}
public class B : Base
{
    public void Init(int info)
    {
    }
}
```

if you need polymorphism then references to Base or, better yet, Thomas' interface are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inheritance, use an interface as a "middle man":

```
public interface IAllThatYouNeed
{
    public void DoSomeStuff();
}

public class A : IAllThatYouNeed
{
    public void Init() {
        // do stuff
    }
}

public class B : IAllThatYouNeed
{
    public void Init(int info) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your solution as well as that of Mathieu which suggests composition instead of inheritance (ie. B instantiate A)

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect solution here. Some possible ways to do it:

An approach would be to make A.Init() virtual, override it in B and make it throw a NotImplementedException/InvalidOperationException.

Init() stays visible, but the user finds out very quickly that it is not to be used (make it explicit that Init(int info) is to be used in the XML documentation and in the message of the exception).

If you don't care about the inheritance part and just want to use the functionalities of class A in class B, don't have B deriving from A and make B instantiate A and use its functionalities.

**Edit:**
You can use an interface implementing the common operations in order to retain inheritance while avoiding to implement Init() in B:

```
public interface IOperations
{
    void DoStuff();
    void Foo();
}

public class A : IOperations
{
    public void Init()
    {
        // Do class A init stuff
    }

    #region IOperations Members

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        // ...
    }

    #endregion
}

public class B : IOperations
{
    A _operations = new A();

    public void Init(int initData)
    {
        _operations.Init();
        // Do class B init stuff
    }

    #region IOperations Members

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        _operations.DoStuff();
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        _operations.Foo();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This can be made even better by using a factory:

```
public static class OperationsFactory
{
    public static IOperations CreateOperations()
    {
        A result = new A();
        result.Init();

        return result;
    }

    public static IOperations CreateOperations(int initData)
    {
        B result = new B();
        result.Init(initData);

        return result;
    }
}
```

This way instantiation code is well encapsulated, the difference between the two Init() methods is hidden from the user code.

Comment: Having B instantiate A seems to me the best solution so far

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it's not yet possible

i tried to do something like this:

```
public class B : A
{
    private override void Init() { }

    public void Init(int x)
    { }
}
```

but Init() it's still visible from the A class

Comment: I tried that too. It happens so because the private override does override, but then it's private, so when looked from exterior it is not found and init() routes to the base class