# How to make a derived method, which takes different arguments than overriden function in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a class, something  like this:

```
class BaseClass
{
  protected int X;
  virtual void ChangeParameters(int NewX)
  {
    this.X = newX;
  }
}

class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass
{
  private int a;
  private int b;
}

class DerivedClass2 : BaseClass
{
  private int a;
}
```

Problem comes when I want to override ChangeParameters() function in derived classes, because each of them can have different number of parameters.

So here comes the question - how can I create a virtual function, which can vary in arguments number in derived classes?

PS. I don't want to use the params keyword, because I'd much prefer the user of the class to know exactly how many parameters he has to pass to the function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I would like to override a method in C#, but I have a different signature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367789/i-would-like-to-override-a-method-in-c-but-i-have-a-different-signature)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. If it is an `override`, the signature **must** be an exact match. If you want different parameters, it doesn't sound like an `override` - after all... how would a caller call it, knowing just the base type? (substitution principal, etc)

```
BaseClass obj = GetSomeConcreteObject(); // actually a DerievedClass2
obj.ChangeParameters({what would go here?});
```

It sounds to me like these are just independent methods. You *could* have a `virtual` method that takes an array (with or without `params`), but then you need to accept that the caller can supply any size.

Answer (score 3):

That's not really possible.

By definition, an override must maintain the same name and set of parameters (aka the signature) as the original method.

How is the runtime supposed to bind your "override" to a method call on the superclass if you are using different parameters? Imagine this were possible:

```
class A
{
    virtual void Foo(int i) { Console.WriteLine(i); }
}

class B : A
{
    override void Foo(int i, int j) { Console.WriteLine(i + j); }
}

// somewhere else

void DoSomething(A a)
{
    a.Foo(1);
}

// later

DoSomething(new B()); // how will b.Foo get called inside DoSomething?
```

If you vary the parameters all you get is an overload.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting trick could be done also using optional parameters, like this:

```
public class Base
{
     public virtual void DoSomething(string param="Hello", string param1 = "Bye") 
     {

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("prm: {0}, prm1: {1}", param, param1));
     }
}

public class Derived  : Base
{
    public override void  DoSomething(string param="Ciao", string param1="Ciao")
    {
          Console.WriteLine(string.Format("prm: {0}, prm1: {1}", param, param1));
    }
}
```

So you can use in code like:

```
Base a = new Derived();
a.DoSomething();
```

Output is:

```
prm: Hello, prm1: Bye
```

But you can now this:

```
Base a = new Derived();
a.DoSomething("Ciao");
```

and output like this:

```
prm: Ciao, prm1: Bye //!!
```