# c++ same name member in parent and child class

Tags: c++

I met a problem in `c++` programming if in `c++` a parent and child class have a member with the same name:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
private:
    int x;
public:
    A(){x=1;}
    void SetX(int i)
    {
        x=i;
    }

};

class B:public A{
private:
    int x;
public:
    B(){}
   int GetX()
    {
        return x;
    }
};
int main() {
    B b;
    cout<<b.GetX()<<endl;
    b.SetX(10);
    cout<<b.GetX()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The program result is:

> -858993460
>   -858993460

Why？ Which `x` is returned?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: it's ok to ask it for learning purpose (see current answers), but the real lesson here is "never put yourself in such scenario": avoid having 2 variables with same name in base and derived class, it will be just misleading and really prone to errors

Comment: i know.it's a program gave by our teacher.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`B::GetX` will always return `B::x`.

`A::SetX` will always set `A::x`.

And since `B::x` is never initialized, its value will be *indeterminate* and printing it will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Actually, B::x is the only x that is initializated in OP code. did you mean A::X?

Comment: @GianPaolo The `B` constructor never initializes `B::x`, and the objet `b` isn't value or zero initialized in any way. The `A` constructor on the other hand assigns to `A::x`.

Comment: How could we konw the functions use which x?

Comment: @501 Closest scope... In the class `B` the closest scope is inside the class `B`, where you have `B::x`. `B::x` *hides* `A::x`, which is `private` anyway and would not be accessable by `B`. And in the class `A` it wouldn't even know anything about `B` or its members, since inheritance is a *one-way* relation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude right, I missed A::x initialization in A ctor, and just considered b.SetX, which actually is called after the first b.GetX call (UB)

Comment: @GianPaolo There is no `b::SetX()`, only `A::SetX()`, which sets `A::x`, not `B::x`.

Comment: @JamesPicone it seems I commented too early after waking up... :(

Answer (score 1):

In C++, a symbol in a child class is defined to "hide" any symbols with the same name in parent classes. This is so that it is not ambiguous which symbol the code is referring to. Note this isn't advisable, for precisely the confusion that your code shows!

There is the keyword `using`, which can "promote" certain parent class symbols into the child classes. But again, this is not advisable in this case!

Look at [Overloading method in base class, with member variable as default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37791164/overloading-method-in-base-class-with-member-variable-as-default/37792007#37792007) for an example of where `using` is warranted, however.

Comment: I think the official term is shadowing

Comment: @JVApen Yes, but that term itself causes confusion, so I use "hide" (in quotes). I've found that "shadowing" for many has the concept of "following along" rather than "putting into the shade", so...